# Dynamic content in header of tile+struts2 application

Tags: java, struts2, tiles

I am working on a struts 2 application with tiles. The content of header in the tile is being populated from an action:
The following code works great but fails when new page with same header is loaded.

**header.jsp:**

```
<ul>
 <s:iterator status="stat" value="masterDataVO.urlMap">
    <li>
     <a href="<s:property value="key"/>"><s:property value="value"/></a>
    </li>
 </s:iterator>
</ul>
```

I want the **header to remain constant** through out the application. But once a new page is reloaded the header fails to display the dynamic content. I know that tiles are not made for displaying dynamic content, and it is bound to not show the content. Can this be achieved through session or something?? Or do I need to scrap the usage of tile entirely??

Comment: Save data to session and display it from there in your header.

Comment: But for accessing session I would have to write scriplet on jsp. Isnt that a bad practice for a MVC application??

Comment: You can also use JSP EL and JSTL. Scriptlets really aren't needed for much of anything anymore and are discouraged across the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data to session and in JSP you can access session with Struts2 tags using OGNL.

```
<s:iterator value="#session['sessionKey']">
```

or

```
<s:iterator value="#session.sessionKey">
```

Comment: ok.. Am able to access it through session and OGNL now. Thanks for that.. But I want to send a map through session to jsp and want key and value from that map. Can you kindly tell how to get key and value from session map..

Comment: It is the same as usually `<s:property value="key"/>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aleksandr M :)